# Using a self-signed certificate for HTTPS connection from iPad to nginx on a private network

Tags: ios, ipad, https, openssl, self-signed

Friends

What are the steps required to establish an HTTPS connection, on a private network (not connected to the Internet) between an iPad and an nginx server?

I have created the certificates (below) and I test the server config with:

`openssl s_client -connect mypi.local:443`

from my MacOS desktop.  It works OK (Enter `GET /` and I get the data from the default page).  Hence I am confident that the certificates on the server are correct.  FLW

- I have taken the Root CA (myca.crt from below), installed it on my iPad.
- I have installed it (VPN & Device Management)
- Trusted it (Certificate Trust Settings)

When I visit `https://mypi.local` in Safari it is not accepted.

The reason I am doing all this is aa have an App that my customers want to run on a private network.  I get the same results from there.

I have run out of options.  What am I doing incorrectly?

---

To create the keys I used the steps laid out [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/self-signed-certificates).  There are many alternatives on this theme around.  I have tried others, with the same results, but this is what I am using now.

These below are the `openssl` commands I used and the relevant part of the server configuration.

```bash
openssl ecparam -out myca.key -name prime256v1 -genkey
openssl req -new -sha256 -key myca.key -out myca.csr # (No challenge password, or company name.  The FQDN is different from my local name for the server)
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in myca.csr -signkey myca.key -out myca.crt
openssl ecparam -out mypi.key -name prime256v1 -genkey
openssl req -new -sha256 -key mypi.key -out mypi.csr # (No challenge password, or company name.  The FQDN is mypi.local, the local name of the server)
openssl x509 -req -in mypi.csr -CA  myca.crt -CAkey myca.key -CAcreateserial -out mypi.crt -days 365 -sha256
```

The server block in `nginx` config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name mypi.local;

    ssl_certificate /home/worik/certs/qcipi.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/worik/certs/qcipi.key;
    :
    :
}
```